# Chained calls in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to express a set of chained calls in a more imperative fashion. For example, image we have a function that takes a list and an element and it appends the element to the end of the list:

```
let insert l e =
  l @ [e]
```

I want to insert a few elements, one at a time. A functional way to do this could be:

```
let myList = insert (insert (insert [] 3) 4) 5)
```

I've recently learned about the `|>` operator, which helps with expressiveness. Together with currying, it can lead to a clean chaining. The problem is that we need to bind the second argument first. This requires defining a function to reverse the arguments (which is actually what `|>` does :P):

```
let myList =
  let insertIn l e = insert e l in
    [] |>
    insertIn 3 |>
    insertIn 4 |>
    insertIn 5
;;
```

This is almost what I want, except the need to defined `insertIn`. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

I was hoping there was a special operator like `$` which could represent the return value of the previous function:

```
let myList =
  [] |>
  insert $ 3 |>
  insert $ 4 |>
  insert $ 5
;;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible approach, which is common in Haskell, is using `flip`:

```
let flip f x y = f y x

let myList =
  [] |>
  flip insert 3 |>
  flip insert 4 |>
  flip insert 5
```

But really, if the `insert` function is one that you wrote yourself, then you should rather consider changing its definition in either one of these ways:

- Flip its arguments so that the list comes last, aka "standard library style":

  ```
  let insert e l =
    l @ [e]

  let myList =
    [] |>
    insert 3 |>
    insert 4 |>
    insert 5
  ```
- Use a named argument, which allows you to pass it out of order, aka "Core style":

  ```
  let insert l ~elt:e =
    l @ [e]

  let myList =
    [] |>
    insert ~elt:3 |>
    insert ~elt:4 |>
    insert ~elt:5
  ```

(Also, a side note: your `insert` is very inefficient because you're copying the whole `l` every time; lists are designed to be constructed by prepending elements to the front with `::`, not appending to the back.)

Comment: I swear I had tried the labeled currying but was getting syntax errors. I just tried you example and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
let (|>) x f y = f x y;;

let myList =
 (((
    []         |>
    insert ) 3 |>
    insert ) 4 |>
    insert ) 5
  ;;

 val myList : int list = [3; 4; 5]
```